# Refering to self type of a trait

Tags: scala, self-type

I wrote a trait to mix into a class the ability to serialize itself to query string parameters, leveraging an existing JSON Writes instance. In order to use that Writes instance as a parameter, I need to know the type into which this trait is being mixed. I'm getting that using a type parameter (which should be the class itself) and a self-type annotation. I'm wondering if there's a DRYer way of doing this, which doesn't require the type parameter?

Here's my code:

```
trait ConvertibleToQueryString[T] {
  this: T =>

  /** Transformation of field names in obj to query string keys */
  def objToQueryStringMapping: Map[JsPath, JsPath] = Map.empty

  /**
   * Convert a model to a Map, for serialization to a query string, to be used
   * in a REST API call.
   * @param writes writer for `obj`
   * @return
   */
  def toQueryStringMap(implicit writes: Writes[T]): Map[String, String] = {
    // Get a map of key -> JsValue from obj
    val mapObj = Json.toJson(this).transform(moveKeys(objToQueryStringMapping)).get.value

    // Convert the JsValue values of the map to query strings
    mapObj.mapValues(jsValueToQueryStringValue).filter(_._2.nonEmpty).toMap
  }
}
```

, to be used as such:

```
case class MyClass(param1: String, param2: Int) extends ConvertibleToQueryString[MyClass]
```

, that final type parameter being the thing that's annoying me. It's fully unconstrained, but it should really just be "the type of the class I get mixed into". Is there a way to express this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the <s>pimp-</s>encrich-my-library pattern:

```
implicit class ConvertibleToQueryString[T: Writes](x: T) {
  def objToQueryStringMapping: Map[JsPath, JsPath] = Map.empty

  def toQueryStringMap: Map[String, String] = {
    // Get a map of key -> JsValue from obj
    val mapObj = Json.toJson(x).transform(moveKeys(objToQueryStringMapping)).get.value

    // Convert the JsValue values of the map to query strings
    mapObj.mapValues(jsValueToQueryStringValue).filter(_._2.nonEmpty).toMap
  }
}
```

Now you don't need the `extends ...` at all on the classes you want to serialize.

Comment: I like this -- what's the notation on the type parameter `[T: Writes]` mean? Also, it probably wasn't clear from my example, but `objToQueryStringMapping` is likely to be overridden by the implementor of the trait I wrote. I suppose here, I make a separate trait for containing that and then `T` has to implement that trait?

Comment: Also, is there a better way to provide `objToQueryStringMapping`, capturing the fact that the is optional? It strikes me as a bit smelly to enclose it in a trait and force the use of `override` in cases like this, where *not* overriding would be more exceptional.

Comment: I managed to track down the answer to my first question -- `[T: Writes]` is shorthand for having an arbitrarily named implicit parameter of type `Writes[T]`. And so far, I am using a separate trait to contain the mapping, which makes my new class declaration: `implicit class ClassToQueryString[T <: QueryStringSerializable : Writes](obj: T)`. I'm still wondering if I can make the provision of the mapping a little more elegant, but that's a nitpick. Thanks for your help!